# Reload Angular Component when only query Parameter Change

Tags: angular

In my Application, I have a Search form. You can access the form by adding query Parameter and the form will then be prefield.

What I want to achieve know is, that if you click on the search Icon in the navigation is that the pre-filled state will clear. The link works so the URL in browser changes. But the Component does of course not re-render.

Is there a way to render the component, or just a LifeCycle Hook to catch this?

Comment: are you read the data from query URL successfully?

Comment: if there are, yes, but the question is more that if the link changes from /search?field1=value1&field2=value2 to /search via routerLink the componet should reset the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to reload the page actually. You can make the different-different link to target the form, like:

```
<a routerLink="/path/to-component" [queryParams]="{'query': 'value1'}">Link 1</a>
<a routerLink="/path/to-component" [queryParams]="{'query': 'value2'}">Link 2</a>
<a routerLink="/path/to-component" [queryParams]="{'query': 'value3'}">Link 3</a>
```

And you need to subscribe the queryParams in the ts file:

```
this._ActivatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(queries => {
    console.log(queries);
    //whenever the link will be clicked
    //queries will be logged here
    //then do something like: refreshForm(queries)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";`

like

```
  public runtimefilter: Subject<DataClass> = new Subject<DataClass>();
```

and in constructor
Observe is

```
constructor(){
    this.subscription = runtimefilter.subscribe(res => {
      this.filter = res;
               this.GetDataFunc();

     });
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.router.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
  this.filter= params["value1"];
    runtimefilter.next(this.filter);
```

}}

Comment: Don't forget to make unsubscribe for the `this.subscription` onDestroy the component